# Google places Autocomplete error: "Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't"

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am creating an simple app where user types any address and gets suggestions, after clicking on any suggestion it will be displayed in a textview.

Autcomplete initialization:

```
try {
      val fields = listOf(
      Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG,
      Place.Field.ADDRESS)
                
      val intent=Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).build(this)
      startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }catch (e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
              }
```

`onActivityResult()` code:

```
if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE){
        val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data!!)
        et_location.setText(place.address)
        mLatitude=place.latLng!!.latitude
        mLongitude=place.latLng!!.longitude
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I type a single alphabet in the Autocomplete, the application crashes saying `Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't`.

What is the problem with my code?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748427/intent-expected-to-contain-a-place-but-doesnt) didn't help me as I want `place.address` to return a string address.

logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=2, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.happyplaces/com.example.happyplaces.activities.AddHappyPlaceActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't.
        at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzft.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.4.0:5)
        at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzeg.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.4.0:3)
        at com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.4.0:2)
        at com.example.happyplaces.activities.AddHappyPlaceActivity.onActivityResult(AddHappyPlaceActivity.kt:253)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Show your logcat. And post relevant codes.

Comment: I have put logcat code.